# Which is the best approach for the below use case using Hadoop ecosystem?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, iot, bigdata

1. I am getting data from more than 1000 sensor units through restservice to my web server, this sensor data I am writing it to single file.
2. Through Flume I am storing these sensors data to HDFS.
3. Through PIG, Hive and MR I am analysing the data and storing back to HDFS 4. After analytics I am writing back to RDBMS through Sqoop.
   Kindly guide me Am I following right approach?

Comment: Sounds right, you're map-reducing in PIG before storing the results, right?

Comment: Yes Sir, Thanks our valuable input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with that pipeline, and if it's meeting your needs...you're golden.

You might want to read a bit on Kafka; maybe Google "Kafka vs. Flume". You might find Kafka compelling, depending on your constraints.

Comment: Yes Sir, Thanks our valuable input.